# Is this simple on/off circuit with MOSFET correct?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I want to control (On/Off) a 12VDC, 10A pump with Arduino. I designed the following simple circuit using a low-threshold MOSFET. Is this circuit correct? Or I need to with an amplifier or a MOSFET driver?

MOSFET I want to use is: NCE3050K

Datasheet to MOSFET: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809291511_Wuxi-NCE-Power-Semiconductor-NCE3050K_C127863.pdf

Diode: US1M

Diode datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2007101707_MDD%EF%BC%88Microdiode-Electronics%EF%BC%89-US1M_C412437.pdf

Circuit diagram:

[image: Arduino driving MOSFET]

Comment: I'd say it looks correct but I would additionally want to know what flyback diode you are using.

Comment: This can work **if** you make sure that the Arduino internally runs on 5 V. Check that when the output is high that is has 5 V. If the Arduino internally runs on 3.3 V then that might not be enough voltage to fully switch on the MOSFET so that it will get hot and damage itself when the 10 A is flowing.

Comment: @JYelton, I forgot to mention. I am planning to use US1M 
  (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2007101707_MDD%EF%BC%88Microdiode-Electronics%EF%BC%89-US1M_C412437.pdf)

I updated the question. I am using this because it works for 1A and can take peak of 30A for few milli seconds.

Comment: You can delete the 100 ohm resistor.  It can reduce EMI in some switching and PWM applications, but it does nothing in a once-in-a-while application like yours.

Comment: With 5V Vgs voltage, the FET has RDSon resistance of up to 16 milliohms. Assuming 10A ID current, there will be 160mV VDS voltage. Thus the FET will waste 1.6 watts as heat when driving the pump. You decide if that works for you.

Comment: It looks fine but you're generating 1.6W in the MOSFET which is getting into the region where you'll have to start putting some thought into getting rid of it.  According to this:
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/smdpack.pdf?fileId=db3a304330f6860601311905ea1d4599
You'll need at least 200mm^2 of 1oz copper to keep your Tj below 175 and that's just the bare minimum.

Comment: @AnalogKid Is the 100R not useful to limit current when changing states? Or is the gate capacitance so small it doesn't matter?

Comment: So small it doesn't matter.  Per the datasheet, the dynamic input capacitance is 2 nF, and the total static capacitance is 4.6 nF at 5 V.  An Arduino output stage that can supply 1 mA will charge this up to 5 V in less than 33 microseconds.  As transient currents go, that's very short.

Comment: @AnalogKid Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The circuit looks ok but there are a few points to watch:

1. Even when fed from a 5V USB an Arduino UNO may only be operating from 4.5V internally and so only drive the FET with 4.5V. Use that in the calculations for ON-resistance.
2. At the 16milli-ohm on resistance for the FET (when driven with 5V) it will drop 160mV when passing 10A. That will result in a dissipation of 1.6W in the FET. It will need a suitable heat-sink.
3. Be careful about the wiring to ensure that the high-current wiring does not cause excessive drops in other areas of the circuit - especially when turning on or off as that can cause damaging transients. Be especially careful about how the grounds are connected together - at the source of the FET would be the best junction point.
4. The diode should be one that can pass the full motor current - a 1N4007 for example is not good enough.
5. When the MOSFET is turned off any inductance present in the wiring to the 12V power source will cause a potentially damaging spike at the drain of the MOSFET. Keep the inductance low (eg twist the 12v and ground wires together) and possibly a capacitor across the MOSFET (drain to source) would be useful in avoiding problems. A value in the region of 0.1uF is a possible starting point.